# How can I create a complex tree map with two different measures

Tags: tableau-api

When I try to set two measures to either size or color on the shelf it makes one disappear. I am trying to have my large boxes be colored to my Execution Team while at the same time having the large box sizes be proportional to my Total Employees and have the smaller boxes within be proportional to my Utilization %.

[image: My Visual]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you only can put a single field on the Color and Size shelf, but ...

- You can place more than one discrete field on the color shelf by holding down the Shift key when you add additional fields. The effect is to generate a combined field, using different degrees of each color.
- If you want the size of the marks to be based on a combination of multiple measures, you can define a calculated field to use on the size shelf -- perhaps `Sum([Employees]) * Min([Utilization]`) in your case. If you use some odd calculation to get the mark sizes you want, you probably still want to use your original fields for the labels and tooltips of course.